# Экономичное хранение матриц. Матричная алгебра

Tags: c++, массивы, математика

*Квадратная матрица А (треугольная или симметричная) порядка n в целях экономии памяти задана в виде одномерного массива из (n + 1)n/2 чисел: сначала идет n элементов первой строки, затем n – 1 элементов второй строки, начиная со второго элемента, и т. д. (из последней n-й строки берется только n-й элемент).*

Заданы целочисленная симметричная матрица А и вектор b размерностью n. Найти вектор с = A * b.

Comment: И что тут сложного? Обычную матрицу на вектор умножить можете? Осталось только найти соответствие, два индекса в один переводящее.

Comment: @Harry "Осталось только найти соответствие".. в этом и проблема. Неделю голову ломаю, всё в пустую.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Осталось только найти соответствие".. в этом и проблема.

Да просто подумать, что перед `m`-ой строкой имеется `n+(n-1)+...+(n-m+1)` элементов и вспомнить, что такое арифметическая прогрессия...

Для матрицы `nxn` элемент `[m][i]` является `m(2n-m-1)/2+i`-м элементом описанного в условии одномерного массива (для `i >= m`; как найти элемент симметричной матрицы для `i<m`, надеюсь, очевидно? :))

Ну, а дальше - просто обращения к `A[i][j]` заменяете обращениями к...